# Remotely Debug WxWidget "Hello World" from Raspberry PI in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, debugging, raspberry-pi, wxwidgets, remote-debugging

My goal is to remotely debug a C++ wxWidget "Hello World" program that was built from source on a Raspberry PI 4 using Visual Studio's debugger that's installed on my laptop.

Things that I've done

- Verified that [this hello world example](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Hello_World) worked on the Raspberry PI itself.
- Confirmed that the wxWidget directory/path that's copied over from the Raspberry PI to my laptop is correct for both the [VC++ Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etfK1.png) and under the [C/C++ property](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V0xQw.png)
- If I were to run a 'bare-bones' C++ program that only included the wx.h header, I get the [wx/defs.h: No such file or directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2G1I.png) error despite the pathing I used for both the VC++ direcotry and the C/C++ properties.

Since Visual Studio copies all the wxWidget header libraries from the Raspberry PI to my laptop, I was under the heavy assumption that all I needed to do was just to include the path to both the C/C++ property and the VC++ Directory as mentioned earlier.

But that's clearly not the case and I'm not sure where to go from here.